# Rails.cache.fetch inserting extra values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, memcached, dalli

We have a page which shows the top groups for our application. The calculation of the leader board is expensive so we cache the results for an hour as follows:

```
@groupboard = Rails.cache.fetch("top_groups", :expires_in => 1.hour) do  
  Group.top_groups
end
```

This is giving an error after the cache has been written the first time. Poking around in the console I see that Group.top_groups returns an array of items that look as follows:

```
[#<Group id: 4, name: "IBP", rank: 6, users_count: 13, leader_id: 4662>, 3887]
```

When I look at the result returned from the cache it looks as follows:

```
[#<Group id: 4, name: "IBP", rank: 6, users_count: 13, leader_id: 4662>, :@new_record_before_save], false, 3887]
```

Does anyone know what would be causing @new_record_before_save and the 'false' value to be inserted into all the entries for this object in the cache?

We are using Dalli, Memcached 1.4.9, Rails 3.2.4, Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: This is a known [Rails bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8020) with the way how marshalling(Marshal.load) is handled by Rails for now. Can you provide more details about you model, or try one of the solutions listed there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug of Rails cache on AR object which has associated object. Try following:

```
@groupboard = Rails.cache.fetch("top_groups", :expires_in => 1.hour) do  
  Group.top_groups.map(&:reload)
end
```

see more on 
https://github.com/mperham/dalli/issues/250